# how can i use encryption algorithm from installed provider on J9 vm?

Tags: java, rsa, jce, encryption, j9

Hi
I am trying to user RSA on J9. The algorithm is offered by the 'J9JCE' provider which is an installed extension(i listed all the existing providers and algorithms and found them) but the exception i get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: JCE provider signer certificates not found/read
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:191)
 at Test.encript(Test.java:26)
 at Test.main(Test.java:42)
```

Comment: If you can, please add a little more code to show how you are going about creating the Cipher instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know the answer to the problem but a workaround is to use the provider from Bouncy Castle which works fine.